# How to use 2D array to build a coordinate system like below? C++

Tags: c++

```
 1 2 3 4 5 
1
2
3
4
5
```

and I want to put some points into coordinate system randomly, so I think that I need to use a 2D array, but I have no idea, please give me a hand.

Comment: `#include <array>` and `std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 5> arr;` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: What do you know about arrays in C++? And technically C++ doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays, but you can emulate that using nested arrays (an array of arrays).

Answer (score 1):

Just make an array of the arrays

```
int array[5][5];
```

And remember that in C++ you start counting from 0 (so you have indexes ranging from 0 to 4)

Answer (score 1):

A better way of representing a 2D coordinate system could be with this type:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
std::vector< std::tuple<int/*x*/, int/*y*/, int/*value*/> > points;//<-- grid points
```

This is a *sparse* approach; instead of recording every possible point, you just record and keep track of those points that actually has a value.
This is also easy to change to non-discrete coords (if/when needed):

```
std::vector< std::tuple<double/*x*/, double/*y*/, int/*value*/ > > points;//<- floating point coords !
```

---

If really hooked on a *dense* coordinate system - you could just use 2 nested `std::array`:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 5> arr;
```

Comment: I would not use `double`s as a key in a map.